# Unreal Engine 4 can't reflect meshes, armature, and animation as per the Blender 3 3d viewport?

Tags: armature, export, mirror, unreal-engine, mirror-modifier

I used a link or streaming plugin or addon like Link Live or Blender to Unreal plugin to import from Blender to Unreal Engine 4.

I need this character, as how it is in the Blender 3d Viewport, comprised of multiple meshes and armature to be exactly reflected in the Unreal Engine 4. Including both the armature and animation/movements.

[image]
[image]

Unfortunately, when I exported this to Unreal Engine 4, via Blender to Unreal plugin, the character came out like this:

[image]

I used the mirror modifier. What went wrong? How do I export the armature and movement to Unreal Engine 4 as well? Thanks

Comment: Since it appears to be working in Blender, I'd consider this question to be about either the third-party plugin or Unreal Engine rather than about using Blender itself so I'd consider this question to be off-topic here.

Comment: Surely mirror modifiers visual effects in blender should also apply to game engines like Unreal Engine and Unity too

Comment: I've no idea. This Q&A site is for questions about using Blender not other software.

Comment: On second thought, regarding the missing faces/meshes, I resolved the issue by simply recalculating normals. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/s5u5ve/missing_texturemeshes_in_import_from_blender_to/) Unreal thread discussed it. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sK2pDByXOE) is how I recalculated normals.